# Unable to read xlsx file to pyspark dataframe from azure blob storage container

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to load data from the Azure storage container to the Pyspark data frame in Azure Databricks. When I read txt or CSV files it is working. But when I try to read .xlsx files I am getting the following issue.

**Apache Spark 3.2.0, Scala 2.12**

Below are the steps I am performing

```py
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.teststorage.blob.core.windows.net",
"**********************")
```

It is working

```py
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .load("wasbs://testcontainer@teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/data/samplefile.txt")
```

Not working

```py
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
  .option("header", "true").option("inferSchema","true") \
  .load("wasbs://testcontainer@teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/data/samplefile.xlsx")
```

Getting below error while loading xlsx files:

```
: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container producer in account teststorage.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.createAzureStorageSession(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:1063)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:512)
at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.initialize(NativeAzureFileSystem.java:1384)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3469)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:537)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader$.readFromHadoop$1(WorkbookReader.scala:35)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader$.$anonfun$apply$2(WorkbookReader.scala:41)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultWorkbookReader.$anonfun$openWorkbook$1(WorkbookReader.scala:49)
at scala.Option.fold(Option.scala:251)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultWorkbookReader.openWorkbook(WorkbookReader.scala:49)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader.withWorkbook(WorkbookReader.scala:14)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.WorkbookReader.withWorkbook$(WorkbookReader.scala:13)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultWorkbookReader.withWorkbook(WorkbookReader.scala:45)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.excerpt$lzycompute(ExcelRelation.scala:31)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.excerpt(ExcelRelation.scala:31)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.headerColumns$lzycompute(ExcelRelation.scala:102)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.headerColumns(ExcelRelation.scala:101)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.$anonfun$inferSchema$1(ExcelRelation.scala:163)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.inferSchema(ExcelRelation.scala:162)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.<init>(ExcelRelation.scala:35)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:35)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:13)
at com.crealytics.spark.excel.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:8)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:385)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:355)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:322)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:322)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:235)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor338.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:295)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Note:** I am able to read from dbfs and mount point.

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises due to the public access level of the blob storage container. When the container has `Private` or `Blob` public access level, the same error occurs for excel files. But when `Container` public access level blob storage container is used, you will be able to read the excel files without error. This is what I got while trying to reproduce the issue.

[image]

A simple solution would be either to change the public access level of the container to `Container`, or to mount the blob storage account to the Databricks file system (which is working for you). If you choose to change the public access level of container, go to the container in your blob storage, and you will find the option “Change access level” where you can select `Container` level.

- Navigate to container of storage account and change access level.
  [image]

[image]

- Go back to Databricks, run the Dataframe read again which works without any error.

```
df2 = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
      .option("header", "true").option("inferSchema","true") \
      .load("wasbs://<container>@<storage_acc>.blob.core.windows.net/data.xlsx")
```

[image]

Please refer to the following document to understand more about accessing blob storage account using Databricks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage

Comment: This is very incorrect answer. I have a blob storage with private access and still I'm able to read excel files using a `wasbs` path and a spark.config setting in cluster's advanced properties (Eg: `spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.key.<storage-acc>.blob.core.windows.net <accesskey>`)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75270203/10532753

Comment: Hey @A5H1Q, the solution given is incomplete but not incorrect. Using `spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.teststorage.blob.core.windows.net",
"**********************")` in notebook and trying to read excel file is still throwing the same error (Same as specified by the user). The provided solution was only for this case. Your solution to configure the storage account access key in cluster's advanced properties works perfectly for any type of container.

Comment: Hey @Saideep, Whatever works for the OP. but keep in mind, Making a container accessible to public is a greater security risk, especially when it allows anonymous users to enumerate the contents of the container. Yeah you're right, if your approach works, it no longer is incorrect. but the method itself is a security risk

Answer (score 0):

Still its not working for me but i tried with bit different approach and copy the blob file to dfs storage by

```
dbutils.fs.cp("abfss://raw@<storageaccount>.dfs.core.windows.net/bank.xlsx","/FileStore/tables/")
```

After doing the above step , one has to create dataframe from the dbfs path and successfully loaded raw data.